# Using CSS to float forms and images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a dropdown box that when the user selects one of the eight images, it displays on the webpage. However, just now the image goes directly above the dropbox and I would like it so the image is displayed on the left and the dropbox on the right. I am just not sure how to code the css as the two are connected so I don't know if div classes would work.

Here's the code:

```
<img id="imageToSwap" src="kittens1.jpg"/>

<select id="kittenlist" onChange="swapImage()">
<option value="kittens1.jpg">Image 1</option>
<option value="kittens2.jpg">Image 2</option>
<option value="kittens3.jpg">Image 3</option>
<option value="kittens4.jpg">Image 4</option>
<option value="kittens5.jpg">Image 5</option>
<option value="kittens6.jpg">Image 6</option>
<option value="kittens7.jpg">Image 7</option>
<option value="kittens8.jpg">Image 8</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
function swapImage(){
    var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
    var dropd = document.getElementById("kittenlist");
    image.src = dropd.value;    
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use `flexbox` you can solve your problem quick and easy. Just create a `.container` wrapping the `<img />` and `<select>` tags and thats it. Even if you want to change the position you can set the attribute `flex-flow` to `row-reverse wrap` and it will display the elements reversed. Let you an example.

```js
function swapImage(){
    var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
    var dropd = document.getElementById("kittenlist");
    image.src = dropd.value;    
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-item: flex-start;
  gap: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">  
    <div class="image">
        <img id="imageToSwap" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
        <select id="kittenlist" onChange="swapImage()">
            <option value="https://via.placeholder.com/150">Image 1</option>
            <option value="https://via.placeholder.com/175">Image 2</option>
            <option value="https://via.placeholder.com/200">Image 3</option>
            <option value="https://via.placeholder.com/225">Image 4</option>
            <option value="https://via.placeholder.com/250">Image 5</option>
            <option value="https://via.placeholder.com/275">Image 6</option>
            <option value="https://via.placeholder.com/300">Image 7</option>
            <option value="https://via.placeholder.com/325">Image 8</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Super overkill.

Comment: In my opinion, flexblox works better than inline elements in this case. With flexbox you can set `justify-content`, `gap` and `align-items` for vertical algnment. It will work even if you remove `.image` and `.dropdown` `<div>` tags from DOM structure. It is just a nowadays aporach.

Comment: True, but you can also not use CSS at all and just use the inline elements as inline elements.

Comment: It depends on your needs at the end. But CSS always gives you more tools to layout your website.

Comment: Can I ask why there are two extra div classes (image & dropdown) does that just help separate them from the container class? :)

Comment: It is just in case. You can skip them and use your usual DOM structure, just adding `.container`.

Answer (score 0):

Both `img` and `select` are inline elements, so there is no line break between them. As long as there is room on the current row of the inline content, they will go next to each other by default. And, if there isn't enough room for both to fit next to each other, you can wrap both within a single element that has `style="white-space: nowrap;"` applied to it.

Also, don't use inline event attributes. That is a 25+ year old technique that we used before there were standards. Use [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) in your JavaScript to set up event handlers.

```js
const img = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");

// Set up a change event handler for the dropdown list
document.getElementById("kittenlist").addEventListener("change", function(){
  img.src = this.value;  // Change the image source to the dropdown value
  img.alt = this.value   // Don't forget the required alt attribute!
});
```

```css
.noBreak {white-space: nowrap;}
#imageToSwap { width:200px; border:1px solid grey; }
```

```html
<span class="noBreak">
  <img id="imageToSwap" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600357077527-930ccbaf7773?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1736&q=80">

  <select id="kittenlist">
    <option value="kittens1.jpg">Image 1</option>
    <option value="kittens2.jpg">Image 2</option>
    <option value="kittens3.jpg">Image 3</option>
    <option value="kittens4.jpg">Image 4</option>
    <option value="kittens5.jpg">Image 5</option>
    <option value="kittens6.jpg">Image 6</option>
    <option value="kittens7.jpg">Image 7</option>
    <option value="kittens8.jpg">Image 8</option>
  </select>
</span>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for answering. Would it be possible for you to go into more detail about addeventlisterner as when I inputed your version of code into my document, it didn't work - including the span tags. I just essentially need the image to float to the left and the dropbox to the right but didn't know how to separate them for the css as I use the images in other webpages too. Any help/ further explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there anyway I can post images to show you the reference I am using vs what I have so far?

Comment: @Emily Yes, click the image icon on the edit/new question toolbar to do so.